# JQuery UI slider Knowing which way the slider is moving

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

I'm trying to implement a slider which can have variable step size. I have a rough Idea, how I'm going to implement it, however I need to now which way the slider is moving, and since I'm new to jquery ui I don't know exactly where i can get the data I need from the slider.

Probably event and ui parameters in the slide event have the variables I need but I don't which.

any help would be much appreciated;

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery slider "slide" event: How do I determine the user's slide direction?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036096/jquery-slider-slide-event-how-do-i-determine-the-users-slide-direction)

Answer (score 0):

well you could add some events so when your mouse goes up, you change the variable to the current position of your range element. when you press down and slide, you look if the range value is bigger then the value you previously saved. I'm not 100% sure, I'm just saying what I would try in the first place

EDIT: this might help

```
var orientation = $( ".selector" ).slider( "option", "orientation" );
```

I found this here: [jQuery slider "slide" event: How do I determine the user's slide direction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036096/jquery-slider-slide-event-how-do-i-determine-the-users-slide-direction)

Comment: Yes that's what I though of. To be honest I was expecting answers like "just use ui.prevSliderValue", I'm making sure if there's any easy way to do it before attempting my own solution

Comment: I just try to help out as much as I can, as I don't have much experience with jquery ui. I'm following jquery courses at school atm :).

Comment: thx :) ... although orientation is not what I need :s. I want to know if the slider moved left or right

Comment: well then only thing I can think of is:
1) save a variable each time the mouse goes up (on your scrubber)
2) whilst sliding check if your saved variable is higher or lower then the current value of the scrubber

else I have no idea on how to do it, I did a bit of research but I didn't find anything useful. hope it helps :)